# Trouble Using DataGrab to Import into Solspace Calendar in EE3

Tags: solspace-calendar, datagrab

Trying to use DataGrab to import into the Solspace Calendar (specifically an XML / RSS feed) but we get this error when we try going to the step that allows us to match fields to the xml data nodes.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'calendar_id' in 'field list':
SELECT `calendar_id`, `title` FROM (`exp_channel_titles`) JOIN `exp_calendar_calendars` ON `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` = `exp_calendar_calendars`.`calendar_id`

ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:122

Is there a solution that would allow us to import XML feeds into the Calendar outside of DataGrab or a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrab's developer added a base import option for Solspace's Calendar module.  Special thanks to http://www.brandnewbox.co.uk

Comment: Does this base import option work as a CSV import (i.e. do you upload an ICS file as CSV?) -- or can it import directly from a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to just import Calendar event data. This is especially because Calendar has several other database tables that need to be populated along with the field/event data so Calendar knows how to handle recurrences, exclusions, etc.